# Hide content in view below a UIDatepicker in iOS 7

Tags: uidatepicker, ios7, xcode5

The new DatePickers in iOS 7 have an attribute that they allow text, images and other content on the view below the datepicker to be partially visible.  This makes the datepicker dial difficult to view clearly due to the content below the datepicker view showing through the pickerdate.  What the best way to call the datepicker and hide the content below the datepicker until the datepicker is dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put white view under it?

Comment: I guess I could add a uiimageview with a white background and use AddSubViee

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just try:

```
    [timePickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```